# How using bootstrap styles with jade framework?

Tags: javascript, css, pug, bootstrap-5

I use jade framework. In my jade file **view.jade** I have strings:

```
| #{mytext.text.slice(0, 30) + '...'}   // The text in my table that needs to be displayed all the time
.tooltip-inner
    | #{mytext.text}                   // Text to be displayed in its entirety in a popup window (in tooltip)
.tooltip-inner
```

I import bootstrap libs in my less file.

I'm not sure it's a good idea to paste the entire styles file

```
/
// Tooltips
// --------------------------------------------------


// Base class
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: @zindex-tooltip;
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: @font-size-small;
  line-height: 1.4;
  .opacity(0);

  &.in     { .opacity(@tooltip-opacity); }
  &.top    { margin-top:  -3px; padding: @tooltip-arrow-width 0; }
  &.right  { margin-left:  3px; padding: 0 @tooltip-arrow-width; }
  &.bottom { margin-top:   3px; padding: @tooltip-arrow-width 0; }
  &.left   { margin-left: -3px; padding: 0 @tooltip-arrow-width; }
}

// Wrapper for the tooltip content
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: @tooltip-max-width;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  color: @tooltip-color;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: @tooltip-bg;
  border-radius: @border-radius-base;
}

// Arrows
.tooltip-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}
.tooltip {
  &.top .tooltip-arrow {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -@tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-width: @tooltip-arrow-width @tooltip-arrow-width 0;
    border-top-color: @tooltip-arrow-color;
  }
  &.top-left .tooltip-arrow {
    bottom: 0;
    left: @tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-width: @tooltip-arrow-width @tooltip-arrow-width 0;
    border-top-color: @tooltip-arrow-color;
  }
  &.top-right .tooltip-arrow {
    bottom: 0;
    right: @tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-width: @tooltip-arrow-width @tooltip-arrow-width 0;
    border-top-color: @tooltip-arrow-color;
  }
  &.right .tooltip-arrow {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: -@tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-width: @tooltip-arrow-width @tooltip-arrow-width @tooltip-arrow-width 0;
    border-right-color: @tooltip-arrow-color;
  }
  &.left .tooltip-arrow {
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -@tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-width: @tooltip-arrow-width 0 @tooltip-arrow-width @tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-left-color: @tooltip-arrow-color;
  }
  &.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -@tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-width: 0 @tooltip-arrow-width @tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-bottom-color: @tooltip-arrow-color;
  }
  &.bottom-left .tooltip-arrow {
    top: 0;
    left: @tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-width: 0 @tooltip-arrow-width @tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-bottom-color: @tooltip-arrow-color;
  }
  &.bottom-right .tooltip-arrow {
    top: 0;
    right: @tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-width: 0 @tooltip-arrow-width @tooltip-arrow-width;
    border-bottom-color: @tooltip-arrow-color;
  }
}
```

**My problem**: I can't figure out how to insert tooltip.top-right.tooltip-arrow correctly, so that when hovering over the text the whole text pops up.